# Show if equation $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ is homogeneous & $M(x,y)x+N(x,y)y\neq0$, then $[M(x,y)x+N(x,y)y]^{-1}$ is integrating factor of equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, integrating-factor

**Questions**

- Show that if the equation $$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0 \qquad(A)$$
  is homogeneous and $M(x,y)\cdot x+N(x,y)\cdot y\neq0$, then
  $[M(x,y)x+N(x,y)y]^{-1}$ is an integrating factor of $(A)\\$
- Show that if the equation $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ is both homogeneous and exact and if  $M(x,y)x+N(x,y)y$ is not a constant, then the solution of this equation is $M(x,y)x+N(x,y)y=c$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

*[Problems taken from [Differential Equations by Shepley L. Ross](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/DIFFERENTIAL_EQUATIONS_3RD_ED/TkQER0zMqQMC?hl=en&gbpv=0), Page $68$, Exercise-$18$ and $19$]*

Any Hint appreciated.

Comment: I'm surprised this question wasn't closed when it was posted in 2016.